# How closing questions help SO?

Tags: support, close-reasons

How closing questions help SO? For new question I think it prevent mail/feed subscription spam and move question away from main/home page. That is good part.

But how about old questions? What the reason to close dinosaurs?

Just to say - "Hey you bastard! We change our policy for about on-topic and anyone who want participate on question must find you through profile mail/links"

When I search through Google or SO I got closed questions as search result.

And I can't contribute to them even if it will valuable contribution.

To understand policy it's good to understand reason behind policy...

**How closing questions help SO?**

**How closing questions help regular SO user (help me)?**

**UPDATE** I am not complain on *closing* subject. Just **how help**.

Comment: *"Hey new user, while we acknowledge the value of this question and provide its information for you, do keep in mind that such questions are no longer on-topic and will be closed"*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> But how about old questions? What the reason to close dinosaurs?

If they are not closed, people think that asking such questions is OK. And when their similar questions get closed, they have a legitimate question - "why was my question closed, when this (old one) exists?".

---

> How closing questions help SO?

Bad, off-topic questions get closed and deleted. What is left should be of higher quality and actually belong on the site.

If we don't close and delete such questions, they will overwhelm the good content.

> How closing questions help regular SO fanatic (help me)?

You come to a site where the content is of high quality and is **relevant**. It is so **because** the bad off-topic content gets closed and deleted.

Comment: So new questions after closing will be deleted? And old questions just marked as closed as deletion will be unethical (because old policy don't forbid those question in that time)?

Comment: *So new questions after closing will be deleted?* I don't see a reason to have a question that can't be answered...

Comment: Unethical? If a post is off topic and will never get an answer (or even if it has answers - it is still off-topic), it should get deleted, yes. If an old post has shown value, it may get a historical lock (which indicates that it is no longer a welcome type of question)